# Loop trough existing images, checking with Promise

Tags: javascript

Desired to have a JavaScript to loop trough a specific *URL* to find existing images using number incrementation (`"https://6od.hu/data/hej_Page_%D.png"`, where `%D` is incremented).

Trying to [Check if image exists without loading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937116/check-if-image-exists-without-loading-it/49017498#49017498) and using the `while` loop:

###### The working code

```js
function imageExists(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image(url);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.onload = resolve;
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (img.naturalWidth && img.naturalHeight) {
        img.src = ''; /* stop loading */
        clearInterval(timer);
        resolve();
      }
    }, 10);
    img.src = url;
  });
}

function loadImg(i) {
  const src_pattern = "https://6od.hu/data/hej_Page_0%D.png"
  let src = src_pattern.replace("%D", i);
  imageExists(src)
    .then(() => console.log("Image exists."))
    .catch(() => console.log("Image not exists."));
}
console.log(loadImg(5)); // true|false needed to return here
```

**How this Promise object can return `true`/`false` for the loop?**

I am just learning these Promise objects, please try to be descriptive. Thank you.

###### Desired loop

```
let i = 1;
while (loadImg(i)) {
  console.log(i + ": " + loadImg(i)); // log all of the existing img than stop
  i++;
}
```

Comment: The `<img>` must be loaded on the actual DOM in order for `.naturalWidth/Height` to return a value other than 0.

Comment: @zer00ne it's enough to preload the image to have it in cache to retrieve the `.naturalWidth/Height`, `.width/height`. Tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/2e0cnswz/1/

Comment: Would be nice to know the reason of the down-wote to correct it :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added missing `return` and changed `then` and `catch` handlers

Also, removed `setInterval`

#### Check one:

```js
function imageExists(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image(url);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.onload = resolve;
    img.src = url;
  });
}

function loadImg(i) {
  const src_pattern = "https://6od.hu/data/hej_Page_0%D.png"
  let src = src_pattern.replace("%D", i);
  return imageExists(src)
    .then(() => true)
    .catch(() => false);
}

(async() => {
  console.log(await loadImg(5));
})()
```

#### Loop:

```js
function imageExists(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image(url);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.onload = resolve;
    img.src = url;
  });
}

function loadImg(i) {
  const src_pattern = "https://6od.hu/data/hej_Page_0%D.png"
  let src = src_pattern.replace("%D", i);
  return imageExists(src)
    .then(() => true)
    .catch(() => false);
}

(async() => {
  for (let i = 1; true; i += 1) {
    const exists = await loadImg(i)
    if (!exists) break
    console.log(i, exists);
  }
})()
```

Comment: Amazing simplicity. Thank you! Here is the final code: [Load all images from URL using integer increment](https://codepen.io/eaposztrof/pen/WNKGqvM?editors=0011)